# Scaling inside the clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How to scale inside a clip?

I dynamically create a clip that simulates a window and calculate its width as

```
stage.stageWidth * my_window_width / my_scene_width;
```

inside the window, i need to create a square that must have a width, coordinate x, and so on, proportionally scaling according to the size of the window screen. Because if the size of the square is set pixel by pixel, then the sizes differ on different screens.

Comment: Can be more? What are you offering?

Comment: When you change the width and/or height of the movieclip, does the content (children) not scale also. How can an adviser re-create your problem using just that one line of code? What are the values of `my_window_width` and that `my_scene_width`? What variable or property is your shown line of actually updating (is there an **equals** sign `=` somewhere in your code? Are we supposed to guess that it's `someNewClip.width = stage.stageWidth * my_window_width / my_scene_width;` then also we have to guess what `my_window` and `my_scene` mean?

Comment: Since not enough info to re-create, you tell us what is the **current result** vs **expected result**? Do you get any errors to help fix? You say _"..If the size of the square is set pixel by pixel, then the sizes differ on different screens"_ okay, but what's wrong with your shown code? Show pictures of this _scale / pixel issue_ if easier than writing about the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You could setting square w/h according to window size...

```
mc_window.square.width = (mc_window.width / 8); //square is eight times smaller
mc_window.square.height = mc_window.square.width; //set to "square" geometry
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a clip that simulates a window:

```
window_bonus = new windowBonus;    
window_bonus.x = stage.stageWidth * indent_to_x_to_photoshop / width_all_file_photoshop;
window_bonus.y = stage.stageHeight * indent_to_y_to_photoshop / height_all_file_photoshop;
window_bonus.width = stage.stageWidth * width_of_photoshop / width_of_all_file_photoshop;
window_bonus.height = stage.stageHeight * height_of_photoshop / height_all_file_photoshop;
```

I get a window like in [figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3awPO.png).

Then I create another clip on the window - [figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRvbf.png).

And on the device it looks like in [figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn1og.png).

I decided to create clips of containers that are not initially visible but they are installed on the window and therefore are scaled with the window,
Inside them already, I load the card image.

But my question is how to scale without containers, 
using width, height, x and y 
for a nested clip?